# ruby on rails で rails console をするとエラーが起きます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

> rails c
>   Could not find listen-3.1.5 in any of the sources
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

listen-3.1-5はインストールしてあります。

> Using listen 3.1.5

Googleで検索した内容は一通り実行しましたが、
一向に解決出来ません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Gemfileはどうなっていますか？ 追記するか、どこか見られる場所に置いてみてください。

Comment: これだけだと確認していることしていないことが全くわかりませんので、"Googleで検索した内容は一通り実行"の具体的な内容と結果を追記してください。

Comment: お困りのようですね。書かれている内容から推測できる回答は多岐に渡ります。質問をするまでの間に、どんなことを試して、それはどんな結果になったか、追記してもらえると回答付きやすくなると思いますよ。その場合は、コメントで追加情報を書くのではなく質問を「編集」して見てください。スタックオーバーフローでは質問の編集は推奨されてます。そうすればエキスパートが回答を書いてくれると思いますのでがんばってください！

Answer (score 1):

他の方も書かれているように情報が無いので問題を予想したレベルでしか回答できませんが、listenを使っているGemをアップデートすれば解決するのでは？

おそらく問題はlisten自体ではないです。例えばguardとかがlistenに依存していて、それらのバージョンに不整合がある場合は上記のようなエラーがでます。

```
bundle update
```

もしくは

```
bundle update guard
```

とすることで解決できる場合があります。guardにあたる部分はlistenを使っているgemをGemfile.lockとかで調べてください。